# Django annotate on created_at

Tags: python, django

I want to get count of records created each day in Django, but I can't make it work. So far I've got this:

```
data = Reservation.objects\
        .order_by('created_at')\
        .extra({'dp': "date(created_at)"}) \
        .values('dp').annotate(count=Count('id'))
```

Which returns

```
<QuerySet [{'count': 1, 'dp': datetime.date(2017, 2, 28)}, {'count': 1, 'dp': datetime.date(2017, 2, 28)}, {'count': 1, 'dp': datetime.date(2017, 2, 28)}, {'count': 1, 'dp': datetime.date(2017, 2, 28)}, {'count': 1, 'dp': datetime.date(2017, 3, 1)}, {'count': 1, 'dp': datetime.date(2017, 3, 1)}, {'count': 1, 'dp': datetime.date(2017, 3, 1)}, {'count': 1, 'dp': datetime.date(2017, 3, 2)}, {'count': 1, 'dp': datetime.date(2017, 3, 2)}, {'count': 1, 'dp': datetime.date(2017, 3, 2)}, {'count': 1, 'dp': datetime.date(2017, 3, 2)}, {'count': 1, 'dp': datetime.date(2017, 3, 2)}, {'count': 1, 'dp': datetime.date(2017, 3, 2)}, {'count': 1, 'dp': datetime.date(2017, 3, 2)}, {'count': 1, 'dp': datetime.date(2017, 3, 2)}, {'count': 1, 'dp': datetime.date(2017, 3, 2)}, {'count': 1, 'dp': datetime.date(2017, 3, 2)}, {'count': 1, 'dp': datetime.date(2017, 3, 2)}, {'count': 1, 'dp': datetime.date(2017, 3, 2)}, {'count': 1, 'dp': datetime.date(2017, 3, 2)}, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>
```

How can I count `dp` records together so that I'd get:

```
<QuerySet [{'count': 4, 'dp': datetime.date(2017, 2, 28)}{'count': 3, 'dp': datetime.date(2017, 3, 1)},..
```

Comment: Btw, extra() is aimed for deprecation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be the last one:

```
.order_by('dp')
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any meta ordering for model Reservation? Otherwise the query should just work fine

Comment: yes i have, but that's why I added order_by into query explicitly. and even when i remove meta ordering it's still not working..